# Date: clearTime

Tags: date, grails

I'm trying to save a date but with clear time. So far its not working. It always has a time even though I already declared clearTime in bootstrap to save the data. I was thinking I must use clearTime in the domain class because I was using mysql db. Please let me know. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a Domain object with a Date field, you should be able to create a setter for it that clears the time portion of the date when it is set:

```
class MyDomain {
  Date date

  void setDate( Date d ) {
    d.clearTime()
    this.date = d
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I figured out why clearTime() is not doing anything in my dateCreated variable. It turns out that the variable 'dateCreated' will be automatically be filled in by GORM with dates AND TIME. I'ts funny because I read it before but totally forgot it.